# What is a fiction story called, which is larger than a short story, but smaller than a novel?

Tags: novel, genre, wordcount, novella

Imagine I write a work of fiction, which is larger than 10.000 words (short story), but smaller than 80.000 words (novel). The external genre is thriller, the internal one -- disillusionment plot.

**What do I call such work so that readers have the right expectations regarding its size?**

Possible answers:

- [Novella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novella): Works between 17,500 and 40,000 words
- [Novelette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novella#Versus_novelette): Between 7,500 and 17,500 words
- [This article](https://owlcation.com/humanities/Difference-Between-A-Short-Story-Novelette-Novella-And-A-Novel) claims that everything larger than 40,000 words is a novel (personally, I'm not sure about that)

Comment: Did you answer your own question? Why do you not want to call it a novella?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T**here are multiple examples of novels that are little over 40,000 words.** Ray Bradbury's *Fahrenheit 451* is 46,118 words. Douglas Adams's *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* - 46,333 words. Erich Maria Remarque's *All Quiet on the Western Front* is ~60,000 words. All are, rather obviously, novels. ([Source](https://indefeasible.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/great-novels-and-word-count/)) Which indicates that your assumption that a novel needs to be over 80,000 words is mistaken.

For shorter works, the source you provide is a good guideline. In particular, this is the guideline followed by the Hugo and Nebula awards, (but notably, other awards use slightly different upper margins on a novella's length. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novella#Word_counts)) That said, Hemingway's *The Old Man and the Sea* is routinely featured on "best novel" lists, although it is merely 26,601 words - on the lower side of the 'novella' length.

I have seen the term **short novel** used sometimes, to describe a work that's comparatively short for a novel. However, I found no formal definition of the term.